# The priority of CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type='submit' class='clsname'>
```

This CSS makes a `blue` border for that input: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ehgz97um/)

```
input{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.clsname{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

But this makes a `red` border for that input: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ehgz97um/1/)

```
input[type='submit']{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.clsname{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

---

I don't know why exactly, But I know it is related to the priority of selectors. I think `input[type='submit']` has a bigger priority than classname, but `input` doesn't have a bigger priority than classname.

Now I have a selector like this: `input[type='submit']` and I need to give a bigger priority to class name. How can I do that? I mean something like this:

```
input[type='submit'] { }
.clsname { /* bigger priority here */ }
```

**Note:** I can do that by `!important`, But I want to know is there any approach else? Because using `!important` is **not** recommended.

Comment: Use `input[type='submit'].clsname, .clsname`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zt61wae/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's specificity. Read more [here on W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Use `input[type='submit'].clsname, .clsname` selector.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zt61wae/).

Comment: Thx ... As I said in the comments, it's exactly what I needed. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can overqualify your selector intentionaly to give it higher priority.

```
input[type="submit"].clsname
```